# mySQL - How to list rows depending on if a specified column includes a specified value?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to list depending on if a row includes a value. Means that, rows which have the specified value should come first. Here is the table structure;

```
------------------
|id|name|grades|
------------------
|1|john|,35,,68,,95,|
------------------
|2|Stefan|,54,,66,,29,|
------------------
|3|Lincoln|,88,,100,,28,|
------------------
|4|Hubert|,15,,67,,29,|
------------------
|5|Lucifer|,24,,66,,47,|
------------------
```

I want to list rows which includes **66** in **grades** column first. So far I have tried this;

```
SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY FIELD (grades,'66'), name DESC limit 10
```

But unfortunately, it doesnt list rows as expected. What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIELD(grades, '66')` compares the entire `grades` column to `66`, it doesn't split it up and look for individual values. You need to use `FIND_IN_SET` to determine if a comma-delimited list contains a value.

```
SELECT * FROM students
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET('66', grades) = 0, name DESC
LIMIT 10
```

`FIND_IN_SET` returns the position of in the comma-delimited list, `0` if it's not found. So adding `= 0` will result in `0` if the grade is found, `1` if it's not found.

BTW, putting comma-separated lists in a table column is generally bad design. You should use a separate table with a row for each value.

Comment: So isnt that should be FIND_IN_SET('66', grades) = 1 to get the rows first if it has included in column ? 0 is always means negative as I know.

Comment: In `ORDER BY`, `0` comes before `1`. There's no negative values.

Comment: For Stefan, `FIND_IN_SET('66', grades)` will be `4`, because `66` is the 4th item in the comma-delimited list. Then when we do `= 0` it will return `0`, so this row will come first.

Comment: What if we don't know where is the value ? It should just check if it includes or not.

Comment: That's what it does! If it includes it, the value will not be 0.

Comment: If it includes `66`, `FIND_IN_SET()` returns something that isn't `0`, and `not0 = 0` is false, which is `0`. If it doesn't include `66`, `FIND_IN_SET()` returns `0`, and `0 = 0` is true, which is `1`. Since 0 goes before 1 when you do `ORDER BY`, all the ones that include 66 will be first.

Comment: No, that will reverse the order. You could use `FIND_IN_SET('66', grades) > 0 DESC`

Comment: Rememer, `true = 1, false = 0`, so `ORDER BY <condition> ASC` puts the false results first.